# if statement when NULL (PHP)

Tags: php

I want to have if the variable = null then he makes it to 1.
if the variable exist do nothing and dont make it again to 1.

i got this code:

```
if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
        if(!$l_NextPage){
        $l_NextPage = 1;
        echo "helaas" . "</br>";
        }
        if($l_NextPage == 1){
            echo "hoi";
            $l_NextPage = 2;
        }else if($l_NextPage == 2){
            echo "doei";
        }
}
```

only the code dont work i tried `empty`, `isset`, `$var == FALSE` but everytime he makes $l_NextPage to 1. is there any solution i tried this too with session but even it don't work!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you want: `if(!isset($l_NextPage))` ?!

Comment: you can use `===` operator which checks also type of variable :)

Comment: answer is `echo "hoi"` and when i click next time on the button its `echo "hoi"` again. but i want if i click first time i get `echo "hoi"` and then when i click again it makes `echo "doei"`

Comment: @Erwin page refreshed after first click ?

Comment: @Anand Patel it refreshed the page when i click on the button.

Comment: Are you trying to check if you're on a certain page?

Comment: @Erwin The variable won't keep the value over new requests! Your server has to meet you every request new! If you tell him your name is Erwin and you want a new request then he doesn't know anymore that your name is Erwin. *It's like your sever would have Alzheimer disease!*

Comment: @Erwin  exctly you should try session for that

Comment: @Fred -ii- i want 4 different divs on the same page, but when i click on button div 1 shows when i click again div 2 show. etc.

Comment: You'll need to provide the good people some more code. As it stands, this is anybodys guess and answers given have all proved to have failed. Not to mention commenting back and forth, will most likely end up having your question closed, soon enough.

Comment: @Fred -ii- i got my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what happen when you refresh page, it assign `$l_NextPage = 1` every time, thats why all the time `hoi` printed

you can use sessions for preserving value of variable after page refresh

try this code

```
// write this line of code at top of php block
session_start();

if (isset($_POST["register"])) 
{
        if (!isset($_SESSION["l_NextPage"]))
        {
               $_SESSION["l_NextPage"] = 1;
              echo "helaas" . "</br>";
        }
        if($_SESSION["l_NextPage"] == 1)
        {
            echo "hoi";
            $_SESSION["l_NextPage"] = 2;
        }
        else if($_SESSION["l_NextPage"] == 2)
        {
            echo "doei";
            //unset( $_SESSION['l_NextPage'] );  unset varibale 
        }
}
```

after reaching at prefixed condition you can unset varible using

```
unset( $_SESSION['l_NextPage'] );
```

i have not tested code but this should work

Comment: i dont reach the `$_SESSION["$l_NextPage"] == 2` only the 1 and `echo helaas`

Comment: sorry for mistake, i have prefixed $ with session variable name, have edited code please check now

Comment: I was going to mention earlier why you were using `$` for `$l_NextPage` in `$_SESSION["$l_NextPage"]` in the first place; one must always follow one's instincts ;-)

Comment: yes Fred -ii- i was just copy paste that variable names thats why, silly mistake by me ;)

Comment: No problemo; everyone makes mistakes ;-) they happen.

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
 if(!isset($l_NextPage)) {
    $l_NextPage = 1;
    echo "helaas" . "</br>";
    }
    elseif($l_NextPage == 1) {
```

(...)

Comment: Yeah, [Riz was *probably* right...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29166730/if-statement-when-null-php#comment46551973_29166730)

Comment: I did say *probably*.

Answer (score -1):

try like this,

```
if(!empty(trim($l_NextPage)))
```

Comment: it will produce `FATAL ERROR Can't use function return value in write context on line number #`

Comment: same problem as here above